# CryptoJS returns wrong values combined with using PHP

Tags: php, hash, md5, sha1, cryptojs

I am experiencing problems connecting to an external API from a vendor. My vendor returns a string hashed with PHP, which I need to validate javascript-side with CryptoJS.

```
PHP: md5(sha1("504099")) = 6a6543b825b80c5bddfa7fcf27395a4c
CryptoJS: CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.SHA1("504099")) = b997bc183982ffdc9ec0c368371a4d4e
```

There is no chance for me to change the PHP output, as it is loaded externally.
I believe I'm combining CryptoJS with md5-sha1 wrong, but I have tried for several hours with no luck.

Any help or input would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
A

Comment: In the PHP functions `md5()` and `sha1()` the 2nd parameter is `false` by default. This causes the result to be returned hex encoded. In the CryptoJS code, however, the data is returned in binary (i.e. as `WordArray`). In order for the CryptoJS code to produce the result of the PHP code, you need a hex encoding as well (e.g. with `toString()`): `CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.SHA1("504099").toString()).toString()`.

Comment: @Topaco You saved my day! Thank you very much